# How to pass the Java map parameters in Spring Webflux get method?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I try to make simple login codes using Spring Webflux. First below codes are Webflux handler and router codes.

**Handler Class**

```
public class UserHandler {
 
    @Autowired
    private UserReactiveMongoRepository userRepository;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> authenticate(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(Map.class).flatMap(mapUser -> {
            String username = (String)mapUser.get("username");
            String password = (String)mapUser.get("password");
            
            Predicate<User> loginFilter = u -> u.getUsername().equals(username) && u.getPassword().equals(password);
            return ServerResponse.ok().body(userRepository.findAll().any(loginFilter), Boolean.class);
        });
    }
```

**Router Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class BlogWebFluxEndpointRouter {
 
    @Bean 
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routesUser(UserHandler handler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/route/user/login"), handler::authenticate);
    }
}
```

Server side handler and router classes are deployed successfully. But the problem is the client codes which  use webclient class. My target is to pass Java Map class parameter in authenticate method of UserHandler class.

```
WebClient client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).build();

Map<String, String> mapUser = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapUser.put("username", "joseph");
mapUser.put("password", "password");
            
client.get().uri("/route/user/login", mapUser).exchangeToMono(u -> u.bodyToMono(Map.class))
            .subscribe(obj -> System.out.println("Login Success : " + obj));
```

But there is no response from the webclient codes. How can I pass the Java map parameter to webclient get method of webflux.

### Update

I change the codes like below,

**Router class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class BlogWebFluxEndpointRouter {
     
    @Bean 
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routesUser(UserHandler handler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.POST("/route/user/login"), handler::authenticate);
    }
}
```

And the following codes are webclient part,

```
Map<String, String> mapUser = new HashMap<String, String>();
mapUser.put("username", "joseph");
mapUser.put("password", "password");
            
client.post().uri("/route/user/login").body(Mono.just(mapUser), Map.class).retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Map.class)
        .subscribe(str -> System.out.println("Login Success : " + str));
```

But the codes throws the following exception,

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of VALUE_TRUE token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of VALUE_TRUE token
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of VALUE_TRUE token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of VALUE_TRUE token
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:242) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Body from POST http://localhost:8080/route/user/login [DefaultClientResponse]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:242) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of VALUE_TRUE token
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

Comment: Try using post instead of using get.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Kindly check my Updated Part

Comment: please look in the documentation, you need to use a multivaluemap https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-body-form